# What is wrong with my malloc/realloc here?

Tags: c, malloc

Update: Per the feedback below which I thought I understood, I've amended the code as follows but it is still troublesome:

```
unsigned int count = 0;
    char* filebuffer;
    filebuffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if (!filebuffer)
    { 

        error(500);
        return false;
    }

    while (fread(filebuffer, sizeof(char), 1, file) == 1)
    {
    count++;
    filebuffer = realloc(filebuffer, count * sizeof(char));
    printf("%lu\n", (count + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }
    if (feof(file))
    {
    *content = filebuffer;
    *length = count;
    }
```

---

Below is some code which is meant to go through a file which is piped through to the function by popen (it's a php file), and store it into a buffer, and then give content* the same pointer and *length the number of bytes read.

However it's not working. Valgrind says:

```
==7608== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7608==    at 0x4C31FCE: strstr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7608==    by 0x4036C0: interpret (server.c:513)
==7608==    by 0x401D66: main (server.c:259)
==7608==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==7608==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7608==    by 0x4C2CF1F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7608==    by 0x40418C: load (server.c:662)
==7608==    by 0x403672: interpret (server.c:502)
==7608==    by 0x401D66: main (server.c:259)
```

The code is:

```
unsigned int count = 0;
    char* filebuffer;
    filebuffer = malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (!filebuffer)
    { 
       printf("oh noes\n");
        error(500);
        return false;
    }

    while (fread(filebuffer, sizeof(char), 1, file) == 1)
    {
        count++;
        filebuffer = realloc(NULL, sizeof(filebuffer) + sizeof(char));

    }
    if (feof(file))
    {
    *content = filebuffer;
    *length = count;
    }
```

Any feedback welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: filebuffer = realloc(NULL, sizeof(filebuffer) + sizeof(char)); this is troublesome

Comment: In addition to the `realloc` error, if you are using an older version of `valgrind` (e.g. `~3.10`), `filebuffer = malloc(sizeof(char));` will give the *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)* warning. To correct it, use  `filebuffer = calloc(1, sizeof(char));` (`malloc` does not initialize allocated space, `calloc` does and older versions of `valgrind` incorrectly flags this)

Comment: Which line is line 513?

Comment: The first code is wrong, you should be allocating `(count + 1)`

Comment: What is `server.c:513` and `server.c:662`, please? This is not a guessing game. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `realloc` does not take the buffer of previously allocated one, also you need to track the the size of the buffer.

```
filebuffer = realloc(NULL, sizeof(filebuffer) + sizeof(char));
```

It should be

```
filebuffer = realloc(filebuffer, <the new size>);
```

But `filebuffer = malloc(sizeof(char));` is just looks as bad as it is, you are allocating ONE byte each type. If you don't know the size of the file in advance, I suggest you allocate block by block.

```
#define BLOCKSIZE 1024
char* filebuffer;
size_t current;
filebuffer = malloc(BLOCKSIZE);
current = BLOCKSIZE;
// in the loop
filebuffer = realloc(filebuffer, BLOCKSIZE + current);
current = BLOCKSIZE + current;
```

Comment: Sure, there are other more severe problems.

Comment: Hi @fluter I've posted an amended code in the original post which does something similar to your suggestion, I"d appreciate any further feedback. I don't know the size of the file in advance because it's being piped through as its a PHP file

Comment: @edd91 need set `count=1;` before the while loop, otherwise the realloc will always get 0, also you need do `fread(filebuffer + count, sizeof(char), 1, file)`, otherwise each time the previous read is overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `realloc` is wrong.

`sizeof(filebuffer)` is equal to `sizeof(char*)`. It does not evaluate to the the size of the array allocated.

You need to keep track of the size using another variable and use that variable. `count` seems to be that variable but it's not clear from your code what you are doing and what those variables stand for.

Also, when you use

```
 filebuffer = realloc(NULL, some_size);
```

it is equivalent to

```
 filebuffer = malloc(some_size);
```

which leads to a lot of leaked memory. To stop the memory leaks, you need to use

```
 filebuffer = realloc(filebuffer, some_size);
```

Comment: Hi @R-Sahu  thanks for your helpful comments. I've amended the code as and posted the new code in the original post but i's still troublesome, any further ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "still troublesome"? What are the symptoms?